# man -K from emacs

Tags: commands

There is `M-x manual-entry` that show concrete `man page`,
but what if I don't know which manual page exactly I need,
from shell I can run `man -K apropos` and see result,
is equivalent functional in emacs, that search in the
same places as `man -K` and then show me the first
search result via `manual-entry` then ask continue, or I satisfied,
and then repeat search if I want?

Answer (score 1):

See documentation for the `man` command (`man-entry` is an alias to it) with `C-h f man`.  You can add an option to be passed to man, as in:
`-K texttosearchfor`, and then navigate the pages with `M-n` and `M-p`.  There are two pitfalls, however:

- you need to protect the space with `C-q` (or emacs will erroneously perform completion),
- you may have to wait quite some time for all pages to be rendered.

Note that the `-k` (lowercase) option is handled nicely.

Comment: So it render all pages, before show? Because of it just hangs for me, while in `*Man ...` there are output of `man` command that it find one page. Is it possible to tell to him show one page at time, because of it is useless if it first found all pages, and only then show them to me, it takes ages before I see the results.